# Firebase cloud function to update a record and send a notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Evening All

Having a few problems performing two actions when a document is created

the below worked until i added the last "then" in the createDocument function where i attempt to send a notification to inform the use via fcm.

```
exports.createRequest = functions.firestore
      .document('requests/{requestId}')
      .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    
        var email = snap.data().requestedFromEmail;
        checkUserInFirebase(email)
        .then((user) => {
          //get user profile
          return getUserProfile(user.user.uid);
        })
        .then(userProfile => {
          return snap.ref.set({ requestedFromName: userProfile.data().fullName, requestedFromId: userProfile.id }, {merge:true});
        })
        .then(value=> {
          return sendNotification(snap.data().requestedFromId, snap.data().requestedByName);
        })
        .catch(error => {return error;})
      }
      )
```

can anyone see where im going wrong, all the examples im finding send the fcm  explicitly from using a exports. Ideally id like to pass the userProfile object through to the send notification function but um not sure how to do that and still set the changes to the document. Full code is below

```
async function checkUserInFirebase(email) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
      .then((user) => {
        return resolve({ isError: false, doesExist: true, user });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return resolve({ isError: true, err });
      });
  });
}

async function getUserProfile(uid) {
    return admin.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .get();
}

async function sendNotification(uid, requestedByName) {
  const querySnapshot = await db
  .collection('users')
  .doc(uid)
  .collection('tokens')
  .get();

const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.token);
console.info(tokens);
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: 'New Request!',
    body: `You received a new request from ${requestedByName}`,
    icon: 'your-icon-url',
    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
  }
};

return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
}

exports.createRequest = functions.firestore
  .document('requests/{requestId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    var email = snap.data().requestedFromEmail;
    checkUserInFirebase(email)
    .then((user) => {
      //get user profile
      return getUserProfile(user.user.uid);
    })
    .then(userProfile => {
      return snap.ref.set({ requestedFromName: userProfile.data().fullName, requestedFromId: userProfile.id }, {merge:true});
    })
    .then(value=> {
      return sendNotification(snap.data().requestedFromId, snap.data().requestedByName);
    })
    .catch(error => {return error;})
  }
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your funciton needs to return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  Right now it returns nothing, which means that Cloud Functions might terminate it up before the work is done.  You should return the promise chain:

```
      return checkUserInFirebase(email)
        .then((user) => {
          //get user profile
          return getUserProfile(user.user.uid);
        })
        .then(userProfile => {
          return snap.ref.set({ requestedFromName: userProfile.data().fullName, requestedFromId: userProfile.id }, {merge:true});
        })
        .then(value=> {
          return sendNotification(snap.data().requestedFromId, snap.data().requestedByName);
        })
        .catch(error => {return error;})
      }
```

Note the return at the start of the whole thing.

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the reply, could i ask if this is the reason that the function update has taken a while to appear in the database? And also does return in the snap.ref pass the updated values to the proceeding then call?